# Refactor foreach statement to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have been working on a project and I'm actually refactoring some code. I have encountered myself with lots of foreach and if statements, which could be easily replace with LINQ.

But I have this code snippet, that I wonder how I could make it more functional style.

```
foreach (var notification in notifications)
{
    if (_emailService.SendEmail(notification.Message.Subject, notification.Message.Body, notification.Message.MailTo))
    {
        successNotificationIDs.AddRange(notification.ID);
    }
    else
    {
        errorCount++;
    }
}
```

The SendEmail method of the EmailService returns a bool. If its execution has been successfully, it will add an IEnumerable of Int to a declared collection (successNotificationsIDs). If not, I will increase the errorCount variable.

Comment: Since you have a sample of working code this should really be posted on Code Review.

Comment: Oh thanks, I will do it. Sorry!

Comment: reSharper is super handy for this..

Comment: Or just supply some broken code that was your attempt at how to do it ;-)

Comment: @MikeChristensen I doubt it would have anything for this snippet

Comment: @Sweeden I also suggest you to add more information to question when you'll post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (i.e. what type of `notifications`, what is `ID` and how you will use errors count)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I would say this loop is not a good candidate for making into a linq statement. Since you are performing an operations (`AddRange` and `SendEmail`) inside it, I would just leave it as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To separate the items of a sequence into all of those that pass some predicate and those that didn't, you can use `ToLookup`.  Use your predicate as the selector:

```
var lookup =  notifications.ToLookup(notification =>
    _emailService.SendEmail(notification.Message.Subject, 
        notification.Message.Body,
        notification.Message.MailTo));

var successfulIDs = lookup[true].SelectMany(notification => notification.ID);
var errorCount = lookup[false].Count();
```

Comment: Depending on the original collection it might also be to just subtract  `successfulIDs.Count()` from `notifications.Count()` without `ToLookup`

Comment: @zerkms Sure, depending on what `notifications` is that may be an option.

Comment: @Sweeden If its some arbitrary type of sequence then you wouldn't be able to do what was suggested.  If it happens to actually be a type of collection that you can efficiently get the count of, then that could be a suitable optimization.

Comment: MSDN ToLookup reference: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549073(v=vs.110).aspx), Example: [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/tolookup)